# Is there any way to sort out double values inside a Google Sheet document?

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, unique, counting

I'm creating a file that should find double values (limited to numbers for now), in a certain column. The first thing i thought was to export the column with the data (to another page of the file), and then do a check by creating an array based on the data of the column needed. The fact is that i don't know how to create an array that can check for double values. I can do that in C++, not in Sheet format.

Best,
Simone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in row 2:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIFS(A2:A; A2:A; ROW(A2:A); "<="&ROW(A2:A)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in row2:

```
=UNIQUE(A:A)
```

This will sort out double values in column A and only list unique values. Make sure below this cell, there are no other relevant cells, unique may overwrite them.